# tomcat and mod jk per page load balancing

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7, load-balancing, mod-jk

I wanted to know how I can offload some heavy load JSP page to another instance of Tomcat by using mod_jk.

Let say under a domain, example.com, I have many JSP pages, eg, query.jsp, modify.jsp, add.jsp, delete.jsp and many more. I noticed that query.jsp has most hit and it generate quite high amount of load. So I am thinking to use mod_jk to offload the query.jsp to another instance.

Within the Apache HTTPD virtual host directive, I know I can put in JKMount /query.jsp worker1, but how about the other pages that I want it to handle by worker2? Will JKMount /*.jsp worker2 works? (Refer lines below)

```
    ...
    JKMount /query.jsp worker1
    JKMount /*.jsp worker2
    ...
```

The reason I didn't go for the proper load balance mechanism in Tomcat is that the coding is not optimize for user session.  If you have any suggestion on how I can improve the resource utilization, feel free to suggest.